# Any examples on how to generate .h JNI files by executing javah within Maven POM

Tags: java, maven, java-native-interface, javah

I can accomplish this via command line, but am trying to use Maven and the POM to automate the creation of a .h file.  I am quite lost - has anybody accomplished this feat.  Any clues would be extremely helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me the `ini-headers-maven-plugin` could be useful for you: https://github.com/alexkasko/jni-headers-maven-plugin